# Why lambda within lambda return a function?

Tags: python, lambda

```
b = lambda x: (lambda x: x)
print(b(88))
```

Why does the python code prints function instead of 88?
Why is this different from the code below?

```
b = lambda x:c(x)

c = lambda x:x

print(b(88))
```

Comment: because that's the result of `b(88)`, a function. Not sure why you expected to see `88`.

Comment: To get 88 you need to do this: `b(1234567)(88)` (as you may notice, the first parameter is useless, because you are not using it)

Comment: Thanks Riccardo. Is it because this is a nested function, so I need to have the arguments twice?

Comment: Try this piece of code, and try to understand why you get 88: `b=lambda x: (lambda x: x)(x); print(b(88))` ;)

Comment: let me try this: lambda is equivalent to define the function, in this case : ```def identity(x)``` ```return x```. So ```lambda x: x``` is equivalent to ```identity```. In order to call this function, I have to provide the argument, ```identity(88)```. Here (lambda x: x)(x) is equivalent to identity(x) rather than identity. So I am calling this function within b, whereas in the previous example I only defined within b not called? Am I understanding it right?

Comment: Where can I find a set of comprehensive name lookup rules btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
b = lambda x: (lambda x: x)
```

Your code is equivalent to this:

```py
def b(x):   # <- This "x" is not used
    def anonymous(x):
        return x;
    return anonymous
```

So you can call it like this:

```py
>>> b("anything")(88)
88
```

This code:

```py
c = lambda x:x
b = lambda x:c(x)
```

is equivalent to:

```py
def c(x):
    return x

def b(x):
    return c(x)
```

So if you call `b(88)`, it will call `c(88)` and return the result.
`c(88)` just returns `88`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are first class objects in python. This means that they can be treated as values. In your case, your `b` function is returning a function (let's call it `c`). Note that I got rid of the `x` parameter in your `b` function, because it's useless.

```
b = lambda: (lambda x: x)
c = b()
```

Now you can call `c`, since it's a function (`c` needs a parameter, `x`):

```
print(c(88)) # this prints 88
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for the help. I think I am getting a hang of it:

```
b = lambda x: (lambda x: x)
```

is equivalent to:

```
def lambda_1(x):
    def lambda_2(x):
        return x
    return lambda_2

b = lambda_1
```

whereas

```
b = lambda x: (lambda x: x)(x)
```

is equivalent to:

```
def lambda_1(x):
    def lambda_2(x):
        return x
    return lambda_2(x)
b = lambda_1
```